# IBOutlet Autolayout constraint constant changing

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have an autolayout constraint defined in Storyboard and set as IBOutlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bottomPanelbottomConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

It's set in the Storyboard as follows:

[image: Storyboard screencap not coming]

Next I change the constant in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    bottomPanelbottomConstraint.constant = -12
}
```

But I still find it the constant to be -3 sometime after this in viewDidLayoutSubviews, which is the value in Storyboard. How can this happen?

EDIT: The following workaround works but is not ideal:

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if bottomPanelbottomConstraint.constant == -3 {
        bottomPanelbottomConstraint.constant = -12
        bottomPanel.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
 }
```

Comment: It might be that you are setting the constraint when the view is loaded but not layouted yet. Have you tried setting the constraint on viewDidAppear?

Also maybe you can put `bottomPanel.setNeedsLayout()`?

Comment: viewDidAppear is too late unfortunately. I want to do everything in viewDidLayoutSubviews at the most for several reasons. I have some tasks after viewDidLayoutSubviews which can hang the UI for 0.5 or so. If I do it in viewDidAppear, problem is user may see the bottom Panel jerking upwards on constraint change which is not ideal.

Comment: The view should be layed out in viewDidLayoutSubviews, correct? Or the subviews can still be pending update in viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Comment: You are telling the system to use specific constant values for different Traits... then you are trying to override that via code. Decide whether you want to use Trait Variations or code.

Comment: Well I also want to see visually in the storyboards. I only tweak some values by bit offsets for iPhone X or iPad in portrait mode. Because there is no way to tweak values for specific devices in Storyboard, only for trait variations.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `layoutIfNeeded()` after changing the constant. It will cause a force update of the layout immmediately.

Comment: I do call it on self.view, even on the bottomPanel as well. But no effect!

Comment: Ohh. Then I think it is possible it might be due to conflicting constraints.

Comment: But it changes back to -12 after I add another subview, which is unrelated!

Comment: The main issue is it is resetting to storyboard value which is strange. No conflict of constraints.

Comment: Do you really need all of those size classes constants?

Comment: Lets say I need them, where exactly is the issue of layout being stuck?

Comment: Look at the edit, as a workaround I am manually checking for constant in viewDidLayoutSubviews & update it. Why is it happening I am wondering.